# trigger form from info class x++

Tags: axapta, x++

I am trying to trigger a form that is already build, from the **info** class within the **startupPost** method.
The logic is to simply open(trigger) that form.
I am not sure if the best logic is to trigger the form from the **startupPost** method or from **activate** method.
Also, I hope the synthax is good, as i'm new in X++ :)

```
EmplTable           emplTable; //NET_PALIN_001_HBDayInfo 
int                 dayOfMonth = dayofmth(emplTable.BirthDate);
int                 mthOfYear  = mthofyr(emplTable.BirthDate);
date                c          =   mkdate(dayOfMonth,mthOfYear,year(systemDateGet()));
str                 emplName   = emplTable.name();
date                dob        = systemDateGet();

 if (c== dob )

   {
   formRun.init(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay)
   new     MenuFunction(MenuItemDisplayStr(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay),MenuItemType::Display).run();
  pause;
   }
//NET_PALIN_001_HBDay is the name of my form
```

Comment: What data type used for `emplTable.BirthDate`? Is it Date or UTCDateTime?

Comment: Declaration of empltable without out initialisation will return null record.

Comment: It is a DATE as it extends TransDate from what I saw in the properties. @Aliaksandr Maksimau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run form either using `FormRun` or `MenuFunction`. Please check the samples below

**Using FormRun:**

```
Args       args = new Args();
FormRun    formrun;
;

args.name(formStr(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay));
formRun = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
formRun.init();
formrun.run();
```

**Using MenuFunction:**

```
Args   args = new Args();
;

new MenuFunction(menuItemDisplayStr(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay), MenuItemType::Display).run(args);
```

So you don't need to use both of them.